# Having Google Assistant return app results instead of web results

Tags: applications, google-assistant, search, google-search, search-history

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone.

It used to be that when I swiped up and keyed in an app name I would see the list of apps I wanted that matched that name on my phone, as I keyed the letters in, and I could then click on the app I wanted.

On the other hand, now when I swipe up and key in keywords Google Assistant shows me a list of web results, and, often no apps.

The web is where all the stuff I don't want to see, lies. It is hardly something that doesn't do me in (when I go to it). I find even that my phone would present me with the list of such results a bit offensive. It is, what I am using on my phone to not access in favor of what I really want: what I downloaded (through Google Play), and, is available, on my phone. When I type in keep, I should be promoted with the Google Keep app, I should not be going though the extra step of going through web search results, and opening/launching the Google Keep app from the web. This extra step, is distracting, slow, and burdening.

If I really wanted something from the web I would type in what I want in chrome. I would type in the name of the website I wanted to access to interact with it socially most of the time, if not, all the time. I know the names of the website I use, I already have chrome history, and, chrome, shows me icons of the body often accessed websites. I don't need (and I don't want), assistant, to do this (not when I type things into my phone, but really, since some mute people cannot speak, we need a switch that displays search apps or search web (you may want things like recipes or cooking times)). However, ad it stands, Google Assistant is unusable.

But when I swipe up on my phone screen I'm really looking for apps, not web results.

So, I wonder whether there is a setting in settings which allows me to control this behavior, favoring results consisting of apps, on my phone (or, in a list of controllable length, optionally, also from the Google Play store), instead of web results.

I want to do this from settings (because there is a lot of things Assistant can do, but web results is not what I want).

Thank you for your support.

Thanks.